# Eclipse: Run on server error

Tags: java, eclipse, apache, tomcat, server

Hello I'm facing strange problem while trying to run the Dynamic web project on eclipse. I have attached the screenshot of the error message.

If I open `localhost:8080/`, I can see Apache Tomcat home page. But when I use `localhost:8080/projectName`, it gives `404 error, resource not found`. I believe it is because of the error I'm getting while trying to run the project.

[image]

Comment: What did you get on console?

Comment: You should reinstall a fresh version of your eclipse.

Comment: @chsdk nothing related to this error is being displayed on console.

Comment: @Stefan I tried but still the same error.

Answer (score 0):

You can try manually deployment of your web project.
Create a war file of the dynamic web project and put that war file under webapps folder of your tomcat installation directory.
Then restart the server and test in browser by entering `localhost:8080/your_projectName`

If it runs then there is problem in eclipse.You can reconfigure server in your eclipse.